# Execute file from matlab

Tags: matlab, execute, simulink

I have a simulink model in Matlab.
how can I build excute file from that model?

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB compiler won't help, you need Real-Time Workshop to generate C code from a Simulink model.

Comment: The Real-Time Workshop can also generate executable code directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the MATLAB compiler toolbox, then all you have to type into the command line is:

`mcc -m yourmfilenamehere`

Comment: Sorry, wouldn't know. Never used Simulink at the office.

Answer (score -1):

You will need the [Matlab compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) to do that. It may or may not be included in your Matlab install. The link explains the how and what and should provide all info you need to get it working. I've never used it, so I can't help you further.

Comment: The Matlab compiler just works for M-files, not for Simulink models.

Comment: I'm sure you can save the model (or at least its plot with all data) to an m-file, which you can then us to create an executable. Otherwise it will probably be impossible.